# DAC connection port SQL Server 2005 SP3

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

We have a named instance of SQL Server 2005 SP3 on an active/active cluster. We find that the Dedicated Admin connection (DAC) is not on one consistent port, the port changes whenever we reboot. We want it to be on a consisten port for monitoring. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This is an excerpt from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190468.aspx):

SQL Server listens for the `DAC` on `TCP` `port 1434` if available or a `TCP` port dynamically assigned upon Database Engine startup. The error log contains the port number the `DAC` is listening on. By default the DAC listener accepts connection on only the local port. For a code sample that activates remote administration connections, see remote admin connections Option.

You will need to review the error log for the port number.

Answer (score 1):

Your monitoring should be using the named instance not the port number as you will not know which instance you are monitoring on that particular port.